# Some function of opencv showing error on some specific scenario

Tags: opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface, computer-vision, native

I am using opencv with android , for that I try my code first on visual studio with opencv , it works fine on it , but something is confusing me in understanding function and their cause of error in `android ndk` like in the sample program

```
    resize(image,image,image2.size());
    image.convertTo(image,CV_32FC4,1.0/255.0);
    image2.convertTo(image2,CV_32FC4,1.0/255.0);

    vector<Mat> channel; 
    split(image,channel);

    Mat mask = image.clone();            // clone function work fine
    //Mat mask = channel[3].clone();     // clone function show me error         

  //  channel.resize(3);  // show error

    Mat it;

    multiply(mask,channel[0],channel[0]);
    multiply(mask,channel[1],channel[1]);
    multiply(mask,channel[2],channel[2]);
    merge(channel,it);
```

***Error's***

When I use `Mat mask = channel[3].clone();` It show me error of `Method 'clone' could not be resolved` but when I use `Mat mask = image.clone();` it works fine. Why is that ?

Same when I use `channel.resize(3);` it show me error in resize function , error is `Invalid arguments 'Candidates are: void resize(?, cv::Mat)'`.

and when I move on to multiply function it show me error of `Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: void multiply(const cv::_InputArray &, const cv::_InputArray &, const cv::_OutputArray&, double, int)'` .

Though these all function are working in visual studio using opencv and they are also working in android when using on different scenario's like when I use

```
Mat alpha1 = ch[3];
Mat alpha =  alpha1.clone();
```

Its not showing error to me in android , but when I use it like `Mat alpha1 = ch[3].clone();` it show me error in android ndk , error's are mentioned above , same for `multiply` when i use

```
split(image,channel);
multiply(mask,channel[0],channel[0]);
multiply(mask,channel[1],channel[1]);
multiply(mask,channel[2],channel[2]);
merge(channel,i);
```

multiply function show me error which i mention above but when I use it like :

```
    split(image,ch);
    vector<Mat> ch0 = ch[0];
    vector<Mat> ch1 = ch[1];
    vector<Mat> ch2 = ch[2];
    multiply(alpha, ch0, ch0);
    multiply(alpha, ch1, ch1);
    multiply(alpha, ch2, ch2);
```

Its not showing me error but I don't know how to merge them and work with it. Hope I clear the question with examples.

I am working on native environment using eclipse with opencv android version of 2.4.8.

Comment: Provide more info on the errors. What errors?

Comment: I updated my question with full explanation

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what is your question. At the end you say that these functions are working in Visual Studio and Android, so where is your problem? Is it when using Visual Studio and C++ or Eclipse and Android? Also, the code you provided compiles fine on my machine with VS2010. Could you provide the exact code with which you get errors?

Comment: What I understand is that he have issue's with these functions using android ndk not with visual studio

Comment: @AldurDisciple some how #Rocket is right , I said that the above function work for me in visual studio with opencv as I tested my program there , but when I am using Android with ndk in eclipse environment the same program showing me error

Comment: I update my question with examples , hope its understandable now , I am using Eclipse for android

Comment: Could you share input and output images?

Comment: Second vignete image is showing lining on images , the second image , when I test images differently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issues. For some reason, ndk and jni doesn't work well with vector indexing. You need to create a temporary instance of that object and assign it and then proceed to do further processing.

I think this will solve your problem.

```
split(image,ch);
Mat ch0 = ch[0];
Mat ch1 = ch[1];
Mat ch2 = ch[2];

multiply(alpha, ch0, ch0);
multiply(alpha, ch1, ch1);
multiply(alpha, ch2, ch2);

vector<Mat> newVec;
newVec.push_back(ch0);
newVec.push_back(ch1);
newVec.push_back(ch2);

merge(newVec, image);
```

For resize and clone, you can't use any of these functions on vector index. You have to create a temporary instance of Mat and use cv::functions over it.

```
Mat alpha1 = ch[3];
Mat alpha =  alpha1.clone();
```

To resize,

```
Mat alpha1 = ch[3];
Mat alhpa1_resized;
cv::resize(alpha1, alpha1_resized, cv::Size(new_cols, new_rows));

// or
cv::resize(alpha1, alpha1_resized, cv::Size(), new_x_scale, new_y_scale);
```

Don't multiply your alpha channel. CH[3]. Keep it as it is and merge. You could also try addWeighted. I think you're doing the same thing.

Comment: Thanks @Froyo this is what i want to know , but its showing error on push_back argument `Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
void push_back(const cv::Mat &)
'`

Comment: oah its work after clean the project but its not showing the output on my device looks it work semantically and fails logically , what about `resize` and `.clone()`

Comment: you tried `channel.resize(3)`, why would this work? this doesn't make any sense. You have to use `cv::resize` function.

Comment: yes but i check your `multiply` option , its not showing me output on android ndk

Comment: though its not showing error too but this whole procedure is not showing output too

Comment: Did you add the alpha channel? IF you don't add the alpha channel, it would show black output.

Comment: Yes i add it after `split` like  `alpha1= ch[3] ; Mat alpha = alpha1.clone();` but still no output

Comment: You also merged it, right? And that multiplication.. it's not giving black image in output, right? use imwrite to check it.

Comment: Now its showing me output but output image contain lining on image , i update my whole code with java code as well , Thanks

Comment: resize was about ch.resize(3) , not about alpha

Comment: if I don't multiply alpha it shows nothing in output using android ndk not visual studio

Answer (score 1):

You could try copyTo() instead of clone():

```
vector<Mat> channel;
split(image,channel);
Mat mask;
channel[2].copyTo(mask);
```

You could try to use mul() and an iterator:

```
for(Mat::iterator I=channel.begin();I!=channel.end();I++) {
   (*I) = (*I).mul(mask);
}
merge(channel,it);
```

I guess that's not a full answer, but maybe it helps solving the problem. This method works for me when handling multiple channels, but might be slower than your code.

Comment: This method work for you with android ndk with eclipse too ? because its still showing me error on `Type 'Mat::iterator' could not be resolved` in a loop and `Method 'mul' could not be resolved` with in a loop , for copyTo() method Method `'copyTo' could not be resolved`

Comment: Ok it was just an idea. I did not test it on Android, sorry. Had some problems with the methods you mentioned and I solved them for my case be using the abovementioned work-around, but not on Android.